# 'mvn package' build errors out with

Tags: java, maven, s3proxy

I'm trying to run a 'mvn package' and get the same error on multiple systems. I'm not sure if this is an error from my lack of knowledge in maven, a configuration issue or an actual Java bug. Has anyone run in to something similar or know a fix?

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ s3proxy ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 26 source files to /tmp/s3/s3proxy-s3proxy-1.9.0/target/classes
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_282). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.tools.javac.util.JavacMessages.add(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/JavacMessages$ResourceBundleHelper;)V
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:473)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.tools.javac.util.JavacMessages.add(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/JavacMessages$ResourceBundleHelper;)V
    at com.google.errorprone.BaseErrorProneJavaCompiler.setupMessageBundle(BaseErrorProneJavaCompiler.java:209)
    at com.google.errorprone.BaseErrorProneJavaCompiler.addTaskListener(BaseErrorProneJavaCompiler.java:96)
    at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneJavacPlugin.init(ErrorProneJavacPlugin.java:34)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:470)
    ... 28 more
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.764 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-02T12:47:20-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project s3proxy: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have doin a mvn clean package, I have tried resolving dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a maven problem.
It comes from error prone Plugin.
See https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/535

Can you upgrade to more recent jdk?

Can you build without the error prone Plugin?

Comment: I've tried upgrading to a more recent jdk and I get the same errors and I can not build without the error prone plugin.

Comment: You cannot comment out the Plugin in pom.xml why is that?